# 'cd' option to change to the previous directory

Tags: bash, scripting, directory, cd

I remember there was a way to execute the `cd` command, automatically returning to the previous directory (without an explicit `cd ...`).
Is it possible?

Comment: Just to be curious, why that vote as "not a real question"? :S Please leave a comment and I'll try to clarify...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just want to go back to the last directory, you can use `cd -`.

If you need more places to go back to, try `pushd <dir>` (instead of `cd <dir>`) and then you can go back with `popd`.

Comment: Accepting. Even if I'm starting a couple of sub-shells in my own script, this sounds as the best alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Found! I can execute it as a sub-shell.

> A command list embedded between
>   parentheses runs as a subshell.

SOURCE: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: Do note that running it in a subshell means that things like setting environment variables to be used outside won't work.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't "return" to the current directory since you never left it in the scope of the parent shell.

Comment: @Ignacio: Yep, but for what I need is fine. @Sorpigal: Good point. I'm aware of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, pushd and popd can come in very handy - they represent operations on a stack of directory locations - allowing you to "travel back in time".

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `cdargs` package. There is [a tutorial](http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2011/01/16/helpful-tips-for-newbie-system-admins/).

Summary:

```
yum -y install compat-libstdc++-296
wget http://www.skamphausen.de/downloads/cdargs/cdargs-1.31-1.i386.rpm
rpm -ivh cdargs-1.31-1.i386.rpm
updatedb
source `locate cdargs-bash.sh`
# You can use any method you like for locating this file and running it
# Also, you need to put it in the ~/.bash_profile file to run it every time you log in
echo source `locate cdargs-bash.sh` >> ~/.bash_profile
cdb
```

Mark a directory and move around:

```
cd /etc/conf/httpd/ext/
mark apaconf
cd /usr/local/src/
cdb apaconf
```

See the link for other commands or search the Internet.