# Bad use of parentheses

Tags: unix, parentheses, pwd

I've been stuck on this for hours:

```
cd /dir1
(cd $HOME); pwd;
```

Why does `pwd` still say `/dir1` and didn't go to my home directory?

Comment: Because [parentheses are evaluated in a subshell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408512/902497).

Comment: Try `(cd $HOME; pwd); pwd` and you will see the subshell is in `/home/user` and the current shell in still in `/dir1`.

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses start a subshell: the shell calls `fork`, and the commands inside the parentheses are executed in the subprocess. The parent process waits for the subprocess to exit then resumes execution. So what's happening is:

- Execution of `cd /dir1`: The shell performs `chdir("/dir1")`.
- Execution of the parentheses: the shell calls `fork`, then the parent process waits for the child to exit.
- Execution of `cd $HOME`: the subshell performs `chdir("/home/jurgen")`.
- The subshell has run out of commands, so it exits.
- The subshell has exited, so the `wait` call in the parent returns.
- Execution of `pwd`: the shell prints its current directory, which is `/dir1`.